# v-for loop not working with imported array

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have 2 files one called **clients.js** with data and one called **clients.vue** and I would like to import the data and list it out in a table in the **clients.vue** file; but I can not access it when importing.

It's working fine if I move the array in to the clients.vue-file (so without import).

My code looks (simplified) like this:

**Clients.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="client in clients">
          <td>{{ client.ClientName }}</td>
          <td>{{ client.ClientId }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import clients from "./data/clients.js";

export default {};
</script>
```

And my **clients.js** file:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      clients: [
        {
          ClientName: 'testname1',
          ClientId: 1
        },
        {
          ClientName: 'testname2',
          ClientId: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I know probably have "activate" the imported array somehow, but i do not know how.

Comment: Are you using this clients.js as `mixin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to expose a property defined in your `component's` data object.

You have imported the `clients` but not injected it into your `data` of `Clients.vue`.

Change the `Clients.vue` like so.

```
<script>
import clients from "./data/clients.js";

export default {
  ...clients
};
```

This will inject the `clients` into `Client.vue`. Then you can use that in your template of `Client.vue`.

#### Alternative:

However this is not a good pattern in terms of readability.

It would be better to have a property in the component itself and then set the property in `mounted` hook.

You can do so in the following way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <!-- use key when iterating -->
        <tr v-for="client in clients" :key="client.ClientId"> 
          <td>{{ client.ClientName }}</td>
          <td>{{ client.ClientId }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import clients from "./data/clients.js";
  export default {
    clients: [] // initial value
  },
  mounted () { // setting clients in mounted 
    this.clients = { ...clients } // use Vue.set if this is a deep nested object
  },
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

#### Mixin way

If you intend to use `clients.js` as an `mixin`.

Then change your script to this:

```
<script>
import clients from "./data/clients.js";
export default {
  mixins: [clients],
}
</script>
```